# Luke 15:8-10, Silver Coin Semedi Headdress in 1st Century Palestine?

Tags: luke, history

In Luke 15, verses 8-10, the Bible tells a story about a woman who loses a silver coin or drachma:

> “Or what woman, if she has ten silver coins and loses one of them, does not light a lamp, sweep the house, and search thoroughly until she finds it? Then when she has found it, she calls together her friends and neighbors, saying, ‘Rejoice with me, for I have found the coin that I had lost.’ In the same way, I tell you, there is joy in the presence of God’s angels over one sinner who repents.” (NET)

Some Biblical scholars presume that this is part of a Jewish headdress known as a *semedi*. I was wondering if there is actual evidence that this was common in 1st century Palestine?

*The Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges*, Volume 39 Page 255

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a good first question. For help in navigating and to see how the exchange works, take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour). (This is a standard welcome message and not intended to discourage you.)

Comment: This garment is known as a *karkush* or *gargush* among Yemenite Jewish women. Worn from puberty until menopause. The coins were sometimes used as an emergency fund in times of scarcity. See (Hebrew) https://teman.org.il/content/%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A9, and image at http://www.museumsinisrael.gov.il/he/items/Pages/ItemCard.aspx?IdItem=ICMS-HSH-JUD160

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching and the practice of putting coins around a headdress appears to originate in Arabic culture and was not present in the Levant prior to the Arab conquests, so while this is a charming interpretation of the lost coin, I don't think it is a contemporary one.

Here is an excerpt from *Near Eastern Archaeology: A Reader*:

> In the Arab Periods (beginning in 640 C.E.), jewelry developed more
> toward styles familiar in bedouin tradition. It became the domain of
> women’s personal property, given to brides upon marriage, worn as a
> kind of bank account (not hoarded), and as amuletic protection from
> misfortune as well as to bring prosperity. Silver and iron were the
> metals prized most, and stones of reddish colors (carnelian and agate)
> and amber were associated with life, health, affection, and
> attractiveness. Chains with pendants, especially of discs and coins,
> were worn with textiles on the head and facial areas. Necklaces had
> crescents, stars, triangles, fish, lizards, toads, “cucumber amulets”
> (cylinder containers), pear-shaped pendants, and an array of smaller
> chains and coins. Religious phrases of praise, blessing, and
> protection, especially against the “evil eye” of envy, psychic and
> social negativity, were inscribed. Bangle bracelets were ornately
> decorated and widened to the clip and cuff styles, and rings were
> complimentary to them. The decorations were appropriate to the
> embroidery work on head and dress textiles. Silversmithing for this
> magnificent jewelry came virtually to an end in the 1960s (C.E.); it
> had been replaced by the mass-produced gold jewelry that developed in
> the 1940s and became popular in the second half of the 20th century.

Platt, E. E. (2012). Jewelry in the Levant. In S. Richard (Ed.), Near Eastern Archaeology: A Reader (p. 203). Winona Lake, IN: Eisenbrauns.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree that this is a very good question, I'd not heard of the potential of the coin in question being one presumably dropped from a woman's headress. The practice I've noticed in photographs of women from cultures at least adjacent to Palestine and surely both headdresses and coins have been around a long time. Perhaps in juxtaposition to Angels mentioned the retrieval of such a coin for restoring her glory compels her giving testimony to her neighbors.